# Add event to dynamically created control

Tags: c#, windows, events, dynamic, listviewitem

I am creating a UserControl. I have a char list of alphabet letters and I want to display those letters, so I create `ListViewItem`s like this:

```
foreach (char letter in letterList)
        {
            this.stack.Children.Add(new ListViewItem
            {
                Content = letter
            });
         }
```

Now I want to add event, so when user clicks on specific letter, something specific happens.
Is there a way to do that, except creating individual `ListViewItem` for each letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
    ListViewItem lstvwalphabet;
    foreach (char letter in letterList)
     { 
            lstvwalphabet = new ListViewItem();
            lstvwalphabet.Content = letter;
            lstvwalphabet.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            this.stack.Children.Add(lstvwalphabet);
     }
```

Event for tracking which item is clicked.

```
    private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      var item = sender as ListViewItem;
      if (item != null && item.IsSelected)
      {
        //Do your stuff
      }
    }
```

Comment: But how I will know, which item was clicked exactly?

Comment: lstvwalphabet_Click has a sender parameter. Just check the sender content